# Attempting to assign multiple variables using jq

Tags: bash, shell

I have a variable named `$db_main_info` that contains the following string

```
 { "host": "env-prod-blah-db.blah.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com", "dbname": "blahblah", "user": "foobar", "password": "foopassfoopass" }
```

I am doing the following

```
read host dbname user password < <(echo $db_main_info | jq -r '.host, .dbname, .user, .password')
```

After executing the above statement when i do `echo $host` it prints the following

```
env-prod-blah-db.blah.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

However the other 3 variables `dbname`,`user` and `password` never get set. I am not sure what i am doing wrong?

I expect the variable `dbname` to take the value `blahblah` and the variable user to take the value `foobar` and the variable `password` to take the value `foopassfoopass`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`jq` prints each field on a separate line, but `read` reads, by default, one line only. One method is to modify the default behaviour of `read`, by assigning the newline character to the `IFS`, which sets this character to be used as the field separator,  and setting the line delimiter to the null string (so that newline no longer serves as a delimiter to indicate the end of line):

```
#!/bin/bash

db_main_info='{ "host": "env-prod-blah-db.blah.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com", "dbname": "blahblah", "user": "foobar", "password": "foopassfoopass" }'

IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' host dbname user password < <(jq -r '.host, .dbname, .user, .password' <<< "$db_main_info")
echo "host=$host"
echo "dbname=$dbname"
echo "user=$user"
echo "password=$password"
```

Comment: "IFS" is just some variable you assign?

Comment: @Dinero No. It is a special shell parameter. You may consider reading [this article](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS) for detailed information.

Comment: Note that the `read` command will "fail" (i.e. return a nonzero status) because it hit the end-of-file before reading the null byte that if expected to terminate the "line". This is normally not a problem at all (and the variables get filled in just fine), but if you've used `set -x` or something similar to make the script exit if any command fails... it'll exit because the `read` command returned a failure status. If you're worried about this, add `|| true` to the end of that line, to give it an alternate command that'll succeed.

Comment: @Dinero  You may also want to read the useful [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66296417/attempting-to-assign-multiple-variables-using-jq/66296657?noredirect=1#comment117207586_66296657) of  [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson)

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for the useful comments. I think another option would be to append a null byte. Something like this: `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' var1 var2 var3 < <(commands; printf '\0')`

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Hmm, interesting idea. It occurs to me you could also have `jq` itself add the null byte: `jq -r '.host, .dbname, .user, .password+"\u0000"'` -- this would put the null before the last newline (the one terminating the `.password+"\u0000"'` line of output), but this shouldn't cause any trouble. There are lots of options here.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thus, if `read` returned a non-zero status, then this would mean it genuinely failed (because `jq` failed somehow). The same can be achieved by `< <(some_command && printf '\0')` in general case.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `jq` alone to see what the problem is:

```
$ echo "$db_main_info" | jq -r '.host, .dbname, .user, .password'
env-prod-blah-db.blah.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
blahblah
foobar
foopassfoopass
```

There's four lines with one field each. You were assuming it was one line with four fields.

You can instead read multiple lines and assign each to the variable:

```
db_main_info=' { "host": "env-prod-blah-db.blah.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com", "dbname": "blahblah", "user": "foobar", "password": "foopassfoopass" }'

for var in host dbname user password
do
  IFS='' read -r "$var"
done < <(echo "$db_main_info" | jq -r '.host, .dbname, .user, .password')

echo "Host: $host, DB name: $dbname, user: $user, password: $password"
```

This results in:

```
Host: env-prod-blah-db.blah.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com, DB name: blahblah, user: foobar, password: foopassfoopass
```