# Passing Variables in CURL GET

Tags: bash, shell, curl, jq, url-parameters

I'm trying to write a sh script that reads data from a JSON, and by parsing, pass the data as variables for a curl request (GET)

The parsing is done correctly but the CURL request continues to give problems.

I parse the variables, after opening the JSON, with the help of JQ:

```
ruleId=$($JSON | jq '.[].ruleId')
alert=$($JSON | jq '.[].alertName')
...
```

I'm passing the variables in this way:

```
curl --data-urlencode "ruleId=$ruleId" --data-urlencode "newLevel=$newLevel" --data-urlencode "url=$url" --data-urlencode "urlIsRegex=$urlIsRegex" --data-urlencode "enabled=$enabled" --data-urlencode "parameter=$parameter" --data-urlencode "evidence=$evidence" "http://localhost:8090/JSON/alertFilter/action/addGlobalAlertFilter"
```

The error that i get back is:

`curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

Can you help me?

Here is my test script:

```
!/bin/sh
#set -e

# Info to test this script
# 1. Start docker 
# 2. Run this command from terminal: docker run -u zap -p 8080:8090 -i owasp/zap2docker-stable zap.sh -daemon -host 0.0.0.0 -port 8080 -config api.disablekey=true -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true
# 2. Get the JSON from api (test for now)
# 3. bash filter.sh
# 4. Check for filter to be set with browser http://localhost:8080/UI/alertFilter/ => view global filter

#open example JSON file (API) and check for alert filter list 
curl -s 'https://api.npoint.io/c29e3a68be632f73fc22' > whitelist_tmp.json
whitelist=whitelist_tmp.json

#Parser WITOUT loop
ruleId=$($whitelist | jq '.[].ruleId')
alert=$($whitelist | jq '.[].alertName')
newLevel=$($whitelist | jq '.[].newLevel')
url=$($whitelist | jq '.[].url')
urlIsRegex=$($whitelist | jq '.[].urlIsRegex')
enabled=$($whitelist | jq '.[].enabled')
parameter=$($whitelist | jq '.[].parameter')
evidence=$($whitelist | jq '.[].evidence')

#Fist test-query WITHOUT url-encoding => not working
#curl -X -4 --retry 2 --retry-connrefused --retry-delay 3 "http://localhost:8080/JSON/alertFilter/action/addGlobalAlertFilter/?ruleId=${ruleId}\&newLevel=${newLevel}\&url=${url}\&urlIsRegex=${urlIsRegex}\&parameter=${parameter}\&enabled=${enabled}\&evidence=${evidence}"


#Second test-query WITH url-encoding
curl --data-urlencode "ruleId=$ruleId" --data-urlencode "newLevel=$newLevel" --data-urlencode "url=$url" --data-urlencode "urlIsRegex=$urlIsRegex" --data-urlencode "enabled=$enabled" --data-urlencode "parameter=$parameter" --data-urlencode "evidence=$evidence" "http://localhost:8080/JSON/alertFilter/action/addGlobalAlertFilter"
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Can you show us the value of all the variables you're using in the `curl` command line?

Comment: @larsks: the json looks like this: [{"url":[ ],"reason":"Incomplete or No Cache-control and Pragma HTTP Header Set","ruleId":"10055","evidence":" ","newLevel":-1,"alertName":"Incomplete or No Cache-control and Pragma HTTP Header Set","parameter":" "}

Comment: Still can't reproduce the problem. [Here is my test](https://gist.github.com/larsks/21325886cbcc90709f8923d75757db4a). Please update your question to include a **runnable example** that reproduces the error you're asking about.

Comment: Pardon, [here you go](https://gist.github.com/teodem/238dfca54fb0c0d6624e61a370b76f44)

Comment: "Update your question" means "put the relevant code in  your question". I've fixed it for you for now, but generally your question should contain all the material necessary for someone to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
whitelist=whitelist_tmp.json
```

to

```
whitelist="cat whitelist_tmp.json"
```

I think the error was occurring because shell was trying & failing to execute "whitelist_tmp.json" as its own command/function instead of piping the contents of the file to jq.

You also want to add the -r option to jq in the variables you are going to pass in curl, like so:

```
ruleId=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].ruleId')
alert=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].alertName')
newLevel=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].newLevel')
url=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].url')
urlIsRegex=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].urlIsRegex')
enabled=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].enabled')
parameter=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].parameter')
evidence=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].evidence')
```

Without the -r option, any strings that jq outputs will be quoted, which could be escaping your script's quotation in the curl command. The -r option tells jq to output the raw string data without any quotation.

Comment: Good one! Really good points, thank you. By testing this out, I'm still having some troubles. I think is related to the fact that "url" parameter is actually an array, and this causes some problems.

Comment: I solved that by using: url=$($whitelist | jq -r '.[].url | .[]') Unfortunately I still got the same error (curl bad illegal format)

Comment: You will need to specify an index of the array (such as '.[0].url' ) if it has multiple elements, as curl cannot accept values with multiple lines for its parameters.

Answer (score 3):

1. jq accepts a filename argument, and it would be better to use that than change `whitelist` to include a call to `cat`:

```
    jq -r 'MYFILTER' "$whitelist"
```

2. Using filters such as `.[].evidence'` makes your script very fragile, as it assumes the top-level array will always have just one entry.  If you want just the first entry in the array, you could specify that, though maybe using `first` would be even more robust:

```
    first(.[].evidence)
```

3. Although jq is fairly light-weight, it is worth noting that all those calls to jq could be reduced to one, though of course your shell script would then have to be modified as well.  See e.g.

- [Attempting to assign multiple variables using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66296417/attempting-to-assign-multiple-variables-using-jq)

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! Yes actually the idea would be, once I've a working script, to use a loop to go through the JSON. This can make the script even more fragile. I'll have a look to the other topic, thx ;)