# Open JSON file locally with JQ

Tags: json, bash, shell, parsing, jq

i'm messing with jq and opening json files.

I'm working on a small parser.
So far I have used (for testing purposes) an api, from which I got the JSON (via curl -s).

```
curl -s 'https://api.npoint.io/c..fc22' > whitelist_tmp.json
whitelist="cat whitelist_tmp.json"
```

Now I would like to import the exact same JSON from the local directory where my script is located but I believe I am making a mistake.
I created a new file called whitelist.json, located in the same folder.

```
jq -s . whitelist.json > whitelist_tmp.json
whitelist="cat whitelist_tmp.json"

#Parser part
ruleId=($($whitelist | jq -r '.[].ruleId'))
alert=($($whitelist | jq -r '.[].alertName'))
```

Comment: @Shawn the funny part is that the content of whitelist is correct. The json is there. The problem is that the next JQ commands have some troubles: annot index array with string "ruleId"

Comment: We can't tell you what's correct without at least a vague idea of what it contains. The error means you do not have elements with that name, but we have no idea what elements you do have, or how they are structured, or what kind of output you expect from these queries.

Comment: You have repeated the antipattern `whitelist="cat whitelist_tmp.json"` in several questions now. You really don't want to store commands in a variable. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68718201/874188) shows the correct idiomatic way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -s command-line option changes the JSON (essentially, it wraps the original JSON in an array), and is likely the source of your problem. Try omitting it.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, thank you :)